# choose to build library or executable in cmake

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm building a library in c++ for which I generate project with CMake.
However, I don't know how to write a good CMakeLists.txt at the top directory of the library.

In fact, actually it works if I want to simply include the library in another project (adding library, linking sources, etc...), but I want that if I generate the library itself without other project, it generate a demo project provided by the library.
So I would like a CMakeLists that

1. link the library in the case of an inclusion in a project
2. build a demo in the case of the CmakeLists is used as the top cmakelists.

My first idea is to search if "project(xxx)" has already been called, but I don't know if this is a good idea. As I don't really know what is the good practice about this I have real difficulties to find information in the documentation.

Comment: If you are willing to share your `CMakeList.txt` for review, this is probably more a question for [Code Review at Stack Exchange site](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick way to detect if your current project is also the top-level project is by inspecting [`PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/variable/PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR.html) and [`CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/variable/CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR.html):

```
if(PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR STREQUAL CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR)
    message("You are building stand-alone!")
endif()
```

But note that this might not be the best solution to your problem. Allowing libraries to be pulled into third-party builds like this requires explicit support from both your library and the enclosing build.

Alternatively, you can build both projects separately, but provide [proper packaging](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.11/manual/cmake-packages.7.html) for your library to make it easy to integrate. This approach is usually more flexible, as it gives your clients the freedom to choose when and how they want to build your library before pulling it into their build.

Comment: Nice! thank you! I will use your first solution now, my library is actually not ready for a proper packaging, but I will try to change it to make it better :)